# How to restrict access to pages when using Angular and Strongloop?

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, strongloop

Strongloop/loopback has built-in ACL to restrict access to properties and functions. My question is, when using AngularSDK, is there a proper way to restrict access to pages?

How can the authorization status be checked in the front-end? I'm using ui-router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [AngularSDK Handling 401 Unauthorized section](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/PTBR/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK#AngularJSJavaScriptSDK-Handling401Unauthorized) of the docs. You can set up a handler to detect when an API call returns a 401 Unauthorized response code and have your UI present a login form. I've done modals and full page redirects, depends on your sensibilities and the structure of your ui-router stuff.

Put the below code (or something similar) inside of your `app.js` inside of a `.config()` block.

Verbatim from the docs:

```
// Inside app config block
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $location, LoopBackAuth) {
  return {
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if (rejection.status == 401) {
        //Now clearing the loopback values from client browser for safe logout...
        LoopBackAuth.clearUser();
        LoopBackAuth.clearStorage();
        $location.nextAfterLogin = $location.path();
        $location.path('/login');
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
 
// In the Login controller
User.login($scope.credentials, function() {
  var next = $location.nextAfterLogin || '/';
  $location.nextAfterLogin = null;
  $location.path(next);
});
```

Given that, you can add an event listener to `$stateChangeStart`, in your `.run()` block -

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  // API call here to check if you get (or simply trigger) a 401
  // whitelist states that can be accessed publicly
  // or blacklist states that cannot be accessed without auth
  // whichever is more straightforward
  // lots of attributes available to check for various metadata attached to states and determine yes/no to continue the state change
});
```

See here for `$stateChangeStart` and the arguments passed to the callback:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

So while it's true that a user could take full control of their browser and thwart this check and force the browser to load the view(s), they still can't access any API calls that require a valid token. So the views will load but the data will not, as long as you have proper ACLs on your sensitive remote methods.

Comment: I'm handling unauthorized requests. I'm not able to hide the menus based on user's role. eg, Admin menu needs to be visible only to users belonging to Admin role.

Answer (score 1):

Typically authorization on the frontend is problematic as the user has control over all his browser. Therefore you should implement the authorization part in your backend. A client might send request that are not allowed, but the server should ensure that they are not executed.

What you can do in order to enable parts when authorized, you could conditionally load additional files in your server-side templates. This could be a JS file that sets certain fields. Unfortunately, this does not avoid a user manipulating your site and circumventing certain security measures.

Answer (score 0):

When using with Strongloop, hiding/disabling of relevant menus, buttons or any controls becomes difficult. That is why I had to post the question.

The best way to couple authorization to AngularJS front end and Strongloop API is following the link.

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.snze0ulwx